# List of list, converting all strings to int, Python 3

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, int, type-conversion

I am trying to convert all elements of the small lists in the big list to integers, so it should look like this:

```
current list:
list = [['1','2','3'],['8','6','8'],['2','9','3'],['2','5','7'],['5','4','1'],['0','8','7']]


for e in list:
    for i in e:
        i = int(i)

new list:
list = [[1,2,3],[8,6,8],[2,9,3],[2,5,7],[5,4,1],[0,8,7]]
```

Could anyone tell me why doesn't this work and show me a method that does work? Thanks!

Comment: By assigning `i = int(i)`, you overwrite the reference in the variable `i`, but not the value inside the list

Comment: @Mirac7 Thank you!

Comment: what if I wanted to convert only the third value from each list? [['1','2',3],['8','6',8],['2','9',3],['2','5',7],['5','4',1],['0','8',7]]

Answer (score 10):

You can use a nested list comprehension:

```
converted = [[int(num) for num in sub] for sub in lst]
```

I also renamed `list` to `lst`, because `list` is the name of the list type and not recommended to use for variable names.

Answer (score 1):

```
for e in range(len(List)):
    for p in range(len(List[e])):
        List[e][p] = int(List[e][p])
```

Or, you could create a new list:

```
New = [list(map(int, sublist)) for sublist in List]
```

Answer (score 0):

Nested list comprehension is the best solution, but you can also consider map with lambda function:

```
lista = [['1','2','3'],['8','6','8'],['2','9','3'],['2','5','7'],['5','4','1'],['0','8','7']]

new_list = map(lambda line: [int(x) for x in line],lista)
# Line is your small list.
# With int(x) you are casting every element of your small list to an integer
# [[1, 2, 3], [8, 6, 8], [2, 9, 3], [2, 5, 7], [5, 4, 1], [0, 8, 7]]
```

Answer (score -1):

In short, you are not mutating `lst`:

```
for e in lst:
    for i in e:
        # do stuff with i
```

is the equivalent of

```
for e in lst:
    for n in range(len(e)):
        i = e[n]  # i and e[n] are assigned to the identical object
        # do stuff with i
```

Now, whether the "stuff" you are doing to `i` is reflected in the original data, depends on whether it is a mutation of the object, e.g.

```
i.attr = 'value'  # mutation of the object is reflected both in i and e[n]
```

However, string types (`str`, `bytes`, `unicode`) and `int` are immutable in Python and variable assignment is not a mutation, but a rebinding operation.

```
i = int(i)  
# i is now assigned to a new different object
# e[n] is still assigned to the original string
```

So, you can make your code work:

```
for e in lst:
    for n in range(len(e)):
        e[n] = int(e[n])
```

or use a shorter comprehension notation:

```
 new_lst = [[int(x) for x in sub] for sub in lst]
```

Note, however, that the former mutates the existing `list` object `lst`, while the latter creates a new object `new_lst` leaving the original unchanged. Which one you choose will depend on the needs of your program.