# Sublist, converting multi digit string to list of single integers

Tags: python, string, list, type-conversion, int

I am trying to convert a multi digit string in sublists, into sublists of single digit integers.
I would like to achieve this using simple list comprehension.

Original list:

```
# [[], ['0000000'], ['2200220'], ['2222220'], ['2200220'], ['2000020'], []]
```

Goal List:

```
# [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0], [2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0], [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0]]
```

The following thread helped me get this far.
[List of list, converting all strings to int, Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43951693/list-of-list-converting-all-strings-to-int-python-3)

If I use this nested list comprehension, the strings turn into a single integer.

```
mylist = [[int(i) for i in s] for s in mylist]

# [[], [0], [2200220], [2222220], [2200220], [2000020], []]
```

I was able to do what I wanted by using two steps that involved importing a module, but this is not ideal.

```
import itertools

mylist = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(mylist))

# ['0000000', '2200220', '2222220', '2200220', '2000020']

mylist_two = [[int(i) for i in str(s)] for s in mylist]

# [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0], [2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0], [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0]]
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction?  Thank you.

Comment: I don't see any reason not to use itertools. You can make it a little more concise importing `chain` from `itertools` and merge the two lines: `[[int(c) for c in s] for s in chain.from_iterable(mylist)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way is to flatten the list using a nested list comprehension, then convert each character in the string to integer.

Here's how you can modify your code:

```
mylist = [[], ['0000000'], ['2200220'], ['2222220'], ['2200220'], ['2000020'], []]
print([[int(z) for z in y] for x in mylist for y in x])
#[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
# [2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0],
# [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0],
# [2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0],
# [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do:

```
data = [[], ['0000000'], ['2200220'], ['2222220'], ['2200220'], ['2000020'], []]
out = [list(map(int, list(s[0]))) for s in data if s ]
print(out)

# [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0], [2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0], [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0]]out = [list(s[0]) for s in data if s ]
```

Since strings are iterable, `list('123')` will create a list by iterating on the individual characters of '123', so it will return `['1', '2', '3']`. We then map each individual digit to an integer.

Comment: As long as I understand he needs the elements of the sub-lists to be integer

Comment: Amazing!  Thank you. 
I know this wasn't in my question, but is it possible to do this without using map as well?  It isn't extremely important, more of a curiosity.

Answer (score 0):

Slight different way, given that each sublist contains just one element:

```
mylist = [[], ['0000000'], ['2200220'], ['2222220'], ['2200220'], ['2000020'], []]

[ [ int(ch) for ch in e[0] ] for e in mylist if len(e) > 0 ]

#=> [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0], [2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0], [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0]]
```